# Excel Auto Data format

Tags: excel, ssrs-2008

I have a SSRS report with some string text like 5-3-2. After I export to CSV file, 5-3-2 changed to date format 5/3/2002. And if I change excel cell format back to text, then it changes to 37379.

How can I get 5-3-2 back? Is there a way to tell excel this is string format at SSRS level? I can add a black space in front of my data" 5-3-2", but I want to know a better solution.

Comment: To retrieve the data, you could try `=TEXT(A2, "m-d-")&RIGHT(YEAR(A2), 1)` but I would recommend re-importing all of the data correctly by specify Text as the target column type.

Comment: If it's a CSV file, you should be opening it with **Notepad(++)** to see what it's actually going to look like to whatever needs the CSV format. Once you open it with Excel, Excel changes the formats and then saves them to your file - making it unusable with whatever needs the CSV.

Comment: This has come up here, and elsewhere, many times. Do not `Open` the csv file in Excel. Instead `Import` the file.  This will open the Text Import Wizard which will allow you to format the column as text before the data is actually written.  (This assumes you haven't already munged the data, and it appears properly in the CSV file if you open it with a text editor).